# What's the rowid of the sqlite data base?

Tags: sqlite

I am new to database and have a sqlite database like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tiles (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, X INTEGER NOT NULL, Y INTEGER NOT NULL, Zoom INTEGER NOT NULL, Type INTEGER NOT NULL,Date TEXT)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TilesData (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT fk_Tiles_id REFERENCES Tiles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, Tile BLOB NULL)
```

If I call the following insert call for the first time:

```
INSERT INTO Tiles(X, Y, Zoom, Type,Date) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?,?)
INSERT INTO TilesData(id, Tile) VALUES((SELECT last_insert_rowid()), ?)
```

What would be the id of Tiles and TilesData?
What's the function of SELECT last_insert_rowid() here?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built your queries on both [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e5d85/1/3) (to easily show you the results) and in a local SQLite instance (to confirm that SQLite (SQL.js) behaves the same as a local instance) using the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tiles (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, X INTEGER NOT NULL, Y INTEGER NOT NULL, Zoom INTEGER NOT NULL, Type INTEGER NOT NULL,Date TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TilesData (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT fk_Tiles_id REFERENCES Tiles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, Tile BLOB NULL);

INSERT INTO Tiles(X, Y, Zoom, Type,Date) VALUES(1, 2, 3, 4, 'Date');
INSERT INTO TilesData(id, Tile) VALUES((SELECT last_insert_rowid()), 'Stuff');

select * from Tiles;
select * from TilesData;
```

In both instances, the `id` in both tables is `1`.

---

The purpose of `select last_insert_rowid()` is to determine what the rowid is of the last successful insert. In your example, it is returning the value from the `INSERT INTO Tiles` query (`1`) and then assigning that to the `id` of TilesData.

We can [demonstrate](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cc0ac/9/3) this works by also specifying the `id` in your first insert and seeing that the `id` of TilesData also matches the forced id.

```
INSERT INTO Tiles(id, X, Y, Zoom, Type,Date) VALUES(123456, 10, 2, 3, 4, 'Date');
INSERT INTO TilesData(id, Tile) VALUES((SELECT last_insert_rowid()), 'Stuff');
```

In this example, I'm forcing the `id` in the Tiles table to be `123456`. This value is utilized as the `id` for the TilesData.

```
select * from TilesData;
```

Results in:

```
id      | Tile
--------------
123456  | Stuff
```